# How to setup login Google Play Games services in unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a small problem with Google Play Games services. When the game started I want to login to Google Play Games services, and its works but when the player die and scene reload then show up popup with Google Play Games services  again. Can I avoid the repeat of login after every reload scene?

To activate/login Google Play Games services I'm using that code attach to main camera

```
void Start () {


    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    if (!Social.localUser.authenticated)
        Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
            Debug.Log("Process completed successfully!");
        });

}
```

Comment: Attach the code to an empty game object that is not destroyed after each scene.

Comment: it is possible if im using button with   SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name); to restart scene?